# Apply a function to substructures automatically

Tags: haskell, recursion, algebraic-data-types

Suppose I am writing a "substitute" function on an abstract syntax tree data type:

```
data Term = Id String
          | If Term Term Term
          | Let String Term Term
          ...

subst :: String -- name of identifier to replace
      -> Term   -- term to replace the identifier with
      -> Term   -- body in which to perform the replacements
      -> Term
subst identifier term = go
  where go (Id id') = if identifier == id' then term else Id id'
        go (If t1 t2 t3) = If (go t1) (go t2) (go t3)
        go (Let id' term' body) = Let id' (go term') (go body)
        ...
```

(Ignore shadowing issues). Notice how tedious it is to write the `If` branch. I have to pattern match, naming the 3 parts, and then reconstruct an `If` applying `go` to each of the 3 parts explicitly. For the `Let`, I have to pattern match, naming the 3 parts, and reconstruct a `Let` applying `go` to the relevant 2 parts explicitly. Is there an easier (pointfree?) way to write this without having to spell out every detail?

Comment: ehird answered the general question; you might find that [unbound](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unbound) answers the specific question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best approach here is to use datatype-generic programming, which was precisely designed for AST-walking tasks like this. Here's an example, using the standard [SYB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) library:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Generics

data Term = Id String
          | If Term Term Term
          | Let String Term Term
          deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)

subst :: String -- name of identifier to replace
      -> Term   -- term to replace the identifier with
      -> Term   -- body in which to perform the replacements
      -> Term
subst identifier term = everywhere (mkT go)
  where go (Id id') = if identifier == id' then term else Id id'
        go x = x
```

This directly expresses that the transformation (in this case, applying the function `go` to any child of type `Term`) should be applied to the whole tree in a bottom-up manner. Not only is this much more concise, but the same code continues to work no matter how many constructs are added to `Term`, so long as the basic recursion scheme stays the same.

Comment: Better yet, simplify the first `go` line to "`go (Id id') | identifier == id' = term`".